# change default value of DropDownFormField form null to ""

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a dropDownFormField with certain items now I want to insert the selected item into my model if the item is selected, since the field is not required I want to insert an empty string "" if the item is not selected.
I couldn't achieve that.

Tried giving a ternary option on onChange.

```
child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
          hint: Text("Select instruction type"),
          items: DummyData()
              .instructions
              .map(
                (value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                  child: Text(value),
                  value: value,
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            if (val == null) {
              setState(() {
                selectedInstructionItem = "";
              });
            } else {
              setState(() {
                selectedInstructionItem = val;
              });
            }
          },
          value: selectedInstructionItem == null ? "" : selectedInstructionItem,
        ),
```

I get a null value while looping and getting values I inserted.

Comment: Variable value will accept  a value from your list. it can't accept any value that doesn't exist  in your list like an empty space " " .

Comment: yes I want to give it manually a empty string value if the dropdown is not seleted rather than the null value I'm inserting now.